# Not able to assign text to UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

error when try to assign a string to the UITextView.
coding as below:-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

        @IBOutlet weak var txtResult: UITextView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         txtResult.text = "ABC"
     }
}
```

Comment: Your Outlet is linked to Storyboard or Xib file?

Comment: What is the *error*?

Comment: "error when": What error?

Comment: error happen on coding txtResult.text = "ABC".

Comment: @Isacc Lim what is the error ? question is still same.Update your code with what error log says,that will help understand things better.

Comment: capture from console --> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @lsacc Lim can you show more code ? Are you sure you have all outlets correctly, and have given correct class to controller.

Comment: hi, i add in my full coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/2227743)

Comment: @IsaacLim Unless you can update your question with the complete error, no one can help you properly. The message you posted in an earlier comment is not sufficient.

Comment: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException –" That's missing half of the whole error message. If you don't give us the complete error message, every asnwers here will be pure guess. Maybe it will point out your real error, but you're clearly calling for luck. Because there is nothing wrong with your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing more error details might help to solve your issue. But you can still solve it by checking few things-:

1) Check for `UITextView` outlet in storyboard-:

[image]

2) Check if you have given correct class to controller . In my case it's `UnderlineViewController` check for yours. Your controller should have same class.

**2.a)** Go to storyboard click on controller and select `identity inspector`.

**2.b)** check class name.

[image]

**Now add text in controller class-:**

```
import UIKit

class UnderlineViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textViewData: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textViewData.text = "Tushar"
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT-:**

[image]

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE NO MORE THEN 1 OUTLET FOR ANY VIEW IN SIMILAR
CONTROLLER.**

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your code and delete the @IBOutlet line of code that you created
2. Delete this in Storyboard:
   [image]
   I think you have few referencing outlets there for 1 object. You need to have only 1. So better to remove all of them.
3. Add new outlet again.
4. It should work.

Comment: thanks, but still got error. when run until that code, the xcode terminate.

Comment: can you please edit your question and add more info like: 1. show me your storyboard as i showed on screenshot and 2. the error itself. otherwise it's hard to guess